# Enable sharing - I don't know which options in the drop-down to choose

Tags: pi-2

[image]

I have connected my Raspberry 2 to my PC with a ethernet cable and a USB cable. I use wifi.
But when I try to enable sharing I don't these options in the drop-down.

1. Ethernet
2. Virtualbox host-only network
3. VMWare network adapter vmnet 1
4. VMWare network adapter vmnet 8
5. Npcap loopback adapter

Which one should I use ? I couldn't get an IP for my IP.

Mine is a fresh pi. I hope I can use it like this. It should have NOOBS. Right ?

Comment: How to set up windows for wifi sharing is off-topic. I would ask this at https://superuser.com/

Comment: Asked there. Should I delete it here ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan Yes, I would delete it here. Otherwise someone at superuser will find a copy of your question here and complain about cross-posting.